# How to take an average of three rows in a dataframe, and assign the index of the first row to the mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 5-minute timestamps as the index and I would like to switch to 15-minute periods. So I would like to take the mean of 3 5-minute periods, and then assign the index value of the first period to that mean, building another dataframe.

```
df1= 
                                    variable_1
(Settlement_Date,)                                
2018-06-30 20:30:00                     4.5
2018-06-30 20:35:00                     3.8
2018-06-30 20:40:00                     4.2
2018-06-30 20:45:00                     4.1
2018-06-30 20:50:00                     6.0
2018-06-30 20:55:00                     3.3
2018-06-30 21:00:00                     1.9
2018-06-30 21:05:00                     2.8
2018-06-30 21:10:00                     3.1
...                                     ...
```

I want this dataframe to become some thing like this

```
df1= 
                                    variable_1
(Settlement_Date,)                                
2018-06-30 20:30:00                     4.2
2018-06-30 20:45:00                     4.5
2018-06-30 21:00:00                     2.6 
...                                     ...
```

I have tried to use a 'for loop', but am having issues getting the date back into the dataframe

```
mean_list = []
date_list = []

for i in range(len(df1)-3):
    mean_holding = df1[:i+3].mean()
    date_holding = df1.iloc[i+3]
    mean_list.append(mean_holding)
    date_list.append(date_holding)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `mean`:

```
df = df.resample('15Min').mean()
```

Alternative solution with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).mean()

print (df)
                     variable_1
(Settlement_Date,)             
2018-06-30 20:30:00    4.166667
2018-06-30 20:45:00    4.466667
2018-06-30 21:00:00    2.600000
```